# DB Syntax Error: CiviMail

Tags: civimail, error

Drupal 7.69, Civi 5.23.0

A colleague just had an issue with CiviMail. She was trying to send a mail to Group "Volunteers" but exclude people in Group "Garden Volunteers". Instead of saying the number of recipients, it just froze on "Estimating..."

[image: Civi estimating number of recipients]

It still says estimating even if saving the draft and exiting.

When we try to submit the mailing, it gives a DB Syntax error.

I checked the Drupal error log and saw two relevant errors.

Pastebin [link 1](https://pastebin.com/2jGQwxHb) | [Link 2](https://pastebin.com/W1F1ceJJ)

I ended up fixing this by just creating a new mailing with the same settings and it worked fine, but would love to work out why the initial issue happened so I Can fix it pre-emptively in case it happens again in the future.

Flushing cache did not solve it.

Cheers!

--

EDIT It's happened again, looks like it's just an issue with one particular smart group. We've definitely mailed to this smart group in the past though.

Someone previously asked what I see when clicking on the spanner icon:

[image: What I see when I click on the spanner]

Comment: can you click on the wrench icon and share the screen shot?

Comment: @PradeepNayak someone deleted the draft mailing unfortunately after the duplicate successfully sent out. From memory, clicking it did nothing.

Comment: It's happened again so I've shared a screenshot of what I see when clicking on the wrench icon

Answer (score 0):

The DB error looks to be caused by this clause: `(civicrm_email.location_type_id != )`

I don't know why that is occurring but check anything related to location types.  Are you using flexmailer/Mosaico?  Do you have any extensions installed that relate to mailing or email address locations?

Comment: Not using Mosaico (couldn't get it to work), Flexmailer is still enabled though. Only other mailing extension enabled is E-mail API (org.civicoop.emailapi)